# JRebel 7.0.1 and WebLogic 10.3.6

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic-10.x, jrebel

I am trying to run a JRebel into a WebLogic 10.3.6. I've just installed it and it seems alright at the beginning but the web application does not get the code changes, it seems like JRebel does not refresh the application in real time. I'm using Eclipse Mars (with the installed plugin), Java 1.7, Maven 3.3.9 and the last version of JRebel, I got a trial license.

Comment: Have you created a rebel.xml in the web application?

Comment: Yes! It is resolved. I did not know that I had to redeploy the application in WebLogic, that is to say, after install JRebel in Eclipse and prepare a server like WL it is necessary to make a new deploy with the rebel.xml. Thanks anyway!